# phpMyadmin style coldfusion app

Tags: coldfusion, phpmyadmin

I am trying to make a simple phpmyadmin like system to work on a server without php. I believe the server is running ColdFusion 8. I can't use dump to get server information. The server is using mysql.

I am currently using

```
<cfquery name="qdb" datasource="#application.datasource#">
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="qdb">#table_name# < br>< /cfoutput>
```

From this page I go to another that outputs all the information in the table by separating the column name from column information.

What I would like to do is get column data type. I need to know which column has the primary key so that I can use that to go to another page to edit the data. I.E. the structure page in phpmyadmin.

I am doing an app for a person on this server and the server admin won't install phpmyadmin. making it difficult to maintain the database.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of < cfoutput query="qdb">#table_name# < br>< /cfoutput> try this...

```
<cfdump var="#qdb#">
```